# Building a time series of r-squared values in R

Tags: r, regression, xts

I have multiple `xts` objects that look something like this:

```
t           x0      x1      x2      x3      x4
2000-01-01  0.397   0.262  -0.039   0.440   0.186
2000-01-02  0.020  -0.219   0.197   0.301  -0.300
2000-01-03  0.010   0.064  -0.034   0.214  -0.451
2000-01-04 -0.002  -0.483  -0.251   0.023   0.153
2000-01-05  0.451   0.375   0.566   0.258  -0.092
2000-01-06  0.411   0.219   0.108   0.137  -0.087
2000-01-07  0.111  -0.039   0.187  -0.271   0.346
2000-01-08  0.131  -0.078   0.163  -0.057  -0.313
2000-01-09 -0.409  -0.022   0.211  -0.297   0.217
.
.
.
```

Now, I am interested in finding out how well the average of the other variables explains each single *x* variable during each period  (e.g. monthly).

Or in other words, I'm interested in building a time series of the r-squared in the following regression:

*x<sub>i,t</sub> =* *<sub>0</sub> +* *<sub>1</sub> avg<sub>i,t</sub> + <sub>i,t</sub>*

where *avg<sub>i,t</sub>* is be the average of all other variables at time *t*. And running that for each *i*  *n* variables and observations *t*   (e.g.  is a month). I would like to be able to run this with any period , where I believe `xts` might be able to help, since there are functions such as [endpoints](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xts/docs/endpoints) or [apply.monthly](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xts/docs/apply.monthly)?

I have years and years of data, and multiple of those xts objects, so the question is, what would be a sensible way to run those regressions, collecting the time series of r-squared values? A for-loop should be able to take care of doing that for each separate `xts` object, but I really don't think a for-loop would be very wise for each single object?

Comment: What the objection to a for loop? Have you tried writing it?

Comment: @MrFlick The reason for that thinking was just that it seems to me that every time someone suggests using a for loop in R, there is actually a "proper", considerably faster way of doing the same. I have a lot of data and at some point speed will become a convenience issue. But would you still suggest "manually" building that with likely multiple nested for loops? How would you suggest separating/recognizing the periods when the amount of observations in each period may vary?

Comment: what about `lst <- split(xts_obj, month(xts_obj$t)); ... lapply(lst, function(l) ...)` ? Or whatever timeperiod you wish to split by